# Configuring Wi-Fi calling with MVNO

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers, wifi-calling

Given a T-mobile issued iPhone that is Wi-Fi compatible and SIM unlocked,

How can I configure wifi calling to work with a corresponding Mobile Virtual  Network Operator (MVNO) (i.e. Mint Mobile)?

Answer (score 1):

You do that by inserting the SIM-card from the MVNO, and then access Settings on the iPhone. In Settings, choose Cellular and then Wi-Fi Calling and turn it on.